# Combining a matrix of TRUE/FALSE into one

Tags: r

If I have this matrix (which I named data):

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[8,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And I want to combine the columns into one single column like this:  (where one TRUE in the row equals TRUE)

```
      [,1]   
 [1,] TRUE 
 [2,] TRUE 
 [3,] FALSE 
 [4,] TRUE   
 [5,] TRUE 
 [6,] FALSE  
 [7,] TRUE   
 [8,] TRUE  
 [9,] FALSE
```

I know I could do something like (using the |):

```
  data2[1:9,1]<-data[,1]|data[,2]|data[,3]|data[,4]…
```

data2 would then contain a single column with the different columns combined. But this is not a good way if I would have lots of columns (for example ncol=100)

I guess there is some simple way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Here is another answer that takes advantage of how R converts between logicals and numerics:

When going from logical to numeric, `FALSE` becomes `0` and `TRUE` becomes `1` so `rowSums` gives you the number of `TRUE` per row:

```
rowSums(data)
# [1] 3 3 0 3 3 0 3 3 0
```

When going from numeric to logical, `0` becomes `FALSE`, anything else is `TRUE`, so you can feed the output of `rowSums` to `as.logical` and it will indicate if a row has at least one `TRUE`:

```
as.logical(rowSums(data))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

I like Tyler's answer though, it might be less efficient (to be proven) but I find it more intuitive.

Comment: @ flodel I benched it and your hypothesis is confirmed. +1

Comment: @TylerRinker, I think that even faster (and to me, also quite intuitive), `rowSums(data) > 0` also works.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `any` with `apply` as in:

```
mat <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100,TRUE), 10)
apply(mat, 1, any)
```