# Combining values Boolean columns to one with Priority in R

Tags: r, reshape2

Gone through below links but it solved my problem partially.

[merge multiple TRUE/FALSE columns into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073839/merge-multiple-true-false-columns-into-one)

[Combining a matrix of TRUE/FALSE into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818295/combining-a-matrix-of-true-false-into-one)

[R: Converting multiple boolean columns to single factor column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361120/r-converting-multiple-boolean-columns-to-single-factor-column)

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
dat <- data.frame(Id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                  A = c('Y','N','N','N','N','N','N','N'),
                  B = c('N','Y','N','N','N','N','Y','N'), 
                  C = c('N','N','Y','N','N','Y','N','N'), 
                  D = c('N','N','N','Y','N','Y','N','N'), 
                  E = c('N','N','N','N','Y','N','Y','N')

)
```

I want to make a reshape my df with one column but it has to give priorities when there are 2 "Y" in a row.

THE priority is A>B>C>D>E which means if their is "Y" in A then the resultant value should be A. Similarly, in above example df both C and D has "Y" but there should be "C" in the resultant df.
Hence output should look like:

```
resultant_dat <- data.frame(Id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                  Result = c('A','B','C','D','E','C','B','NA')
)
```

I have tried this:

```
library(reshape2)

new_df <- melt(dat, "Id", variable.name = "Result")
new_df <-new_df[new_df$value == "Y", c("Id", "Result")]
```

But the problem is doesn't handle the priority thing, it creates 2 rows for the same Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tmp = data.frame(ID = dat[,1],
                 Result = col_order[apply(
                     X = dat[col_order],
                     MARGIN = 1,
                     FUN = function(x) which(x == "Y")[1])],
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tmp$Result[is.na(tmp$Result)] = "Not Present"
tmp
#  ID      Result
#1  1           A
#2  2           B
#3  3           C
#4  4           D
#5  5           E
#6  6           C
#7  7           B
#8  8 Not Present
```

Comment: Thanks!! this solves. Can I get "NA" as something like "Not Present"